# Why does dig succeed if I add an SOA query and fail when I do not?

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

When I do this `dig` I get no answer...

```
red@localhost:~$ dig +noall +answer name-one.name-two.com @mydns-server.name-one.com
```

... but when add `name-two.com soa` I get an answer for `name-one.name-two.com` ...

```
red@localhost:~$ dig +noall +answer name-one.name-two.com name-two.com soa @mydns-server.name-one.com
name-one.name-two.com.   868     IN      A       xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
name-two.com.         2926    IN      SOA     ns41.name-three.com. dns.name-four.net. 2013120202 28800 7200 604800 600
```

... what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: If you removed the `+noall` part, dig would probably tell you

Comment: remove the `+noall` tells me `NXDOMAIN` without the `soa` query (as one would expect). But with the `soa` in the dig command it gives me the answer.  I just wondering why dig behaves this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from `dig -h`:

```
Usage:  dig [@global-server] [domain] [q-type] [q-class] {q-opt}
            {global-d-opt} host [@local-server] {local-d-opt}
            [ host [@local-server] {local-d-opt} [...]]

        [...]

        global d-opts and servers (before host name) affect all queries.
        local d-opts and servers (after host name) affect only that lookup.
```

When you write:

```
dig +noall +answer name-one.name-two.com @mydns-server.name-one.com
```

`dig` treats it as:

> `+noall +answer`
>    - global options, applies to all queries
>
> `name-one.name-two.com @mydns-server.name-one.com`
>    - host to lookup, at a specific name server

But when you write:

```
dig +noall +answer name-one.name-two.com name-two.com soa @mydns-server.name-one.com
```

`dig` treats it as:

> `+noall +answer`
>    - global options, applies to all
>
> `name-one.name-two.com`
>    - host to lookup
>
> `name-two.com soa @mydns-server.name-one.com`
>    - another lookup for a SOA RR, but this time, at a specific server

So the A RR response you receive for the first host is not from @mydns-server.name-one.com.

Comment: that's does appear to be the case.  Since `dig name-one.name-two.com @mydns-server.name-one.com` returns NXDOMAIN yet `dig name-one.name-two.com name-two.com soa @mydns-server.name-one.com` returns an answer for both the 'A' RR and the 'SOA' RR.

Comment: @RedCricket My bad, take a look at the update